# Python: download csv files of historical data from a web that requires login

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup, request

After an extensive web search, I could not figure out how to solve my problem.   Namely, I want to download daily csv files of historical data from a sunnyportal web that requires login. This is the login page: https://www.sunnyportal.com/Login

[image]

After logged in, the following shows a page from which the csv will be downloaded. As you can see, this is the Analysis page (selected from the left-hand side). Below the big graph, there is a date picker to select the date of the year. On the bottom right corner, there is a download button. By clicking this button, the csv for that specific date will be downloaded.

[image]

My aim is to download csv for each day (or can also period) across many years. I know my effort below is still far from the objective, but I have no ide how to proceed.

```
import requests

s = requests.Session()
site_url = r'https://www.sunnyportal.com/Login'
s.get(site_url)
s.post(site_url, data={'_username': 'myusername', '_password': 'mypassword'})

file_url =r'https://www.sunnyportal.com/FixedPages/AnalysisTool.aspx'
s.get(file_url)
```

Comment: And what happens? Does the `post` fail? Or something else?

Comment: I got ```Response [200]```. Then, how to download the file?

Answer (score 0):

When I try to login, the parameters used are looking like this (you can use F12 Developer Console in Chrome or Firefox to watch the POST request)

```
ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$Logincontrol1$txtUserName = my@email.com
ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$Logincontrol1$txtPassword = test
```

I first though the parameters are hidden behind some javascript encoding and generated on the fly, but it seems these are the *real* parameters in the post request, beside the obscure names.

If this works, then you have to find out how the website identifies already logged in users. This could be a cookie, some kind of session id in the url or a http request header. Then you have to emulate that.

Comment: I can login now. But don't know yet how to download daily data